# procedure and prerequisites for installing selenium

Tags: selenium

I am a manual tester and would like to upgrade to automation so i would like to go for Selenium. But i am totally new to selenium. So I would like to gain some knowledge on selenium. For that i would like to install selenium and practice. But i did not  have any idea. I watched some youtube videos and installed selenium ide.  But iam not getting idea how selenium tool is used. Is selenium IDE is sufficient or What is the use of Selenium RC. I would like to use Java as my language. So i want to know what all the things to be downloaded and installed for using selenium tool.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search for something like "getting started with selenium"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Selenium IDE version look at the [Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/) to record and convert tests into code.

There is [a full video tutorial](http://seleniumsimplified.com/get-started/) for setting up Selenium, Java, Maven and an IDE to start building and running tests.